# Easyrtc permission denied and usermedia failed

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, easyrtc

I am using [hublin](https://github.com/linagora/hublin). the camera and microphone was working fine locally but when i uploaded to server. camera permission pop does not appear, it just silently fails and at console there is error of

```
easyrtc.js:2100 invoking error callback PermissionDeniedError
easyrtc.js:2085 getusermedia failed
```

The problem is both with chrome and chromium however asking permission at firefox.

Also i tried to give permission manually but there is no cam-cross icon in rightcorner. In chrome settings>advanced settings>content-settings>camera>manage-exceptions there is no way to manually add specific url for allowing permission as in firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using of HTTP**S** for WebRTC applications is mandatory in Chrome. So, it just doesn't show permission dialog when working on a plain HTTP.

Hence, you should configure **secure** HTTP (HTTP**S**) on the web server (you can use certificates from LetsEncrypt - work like a charm). Or you can try to use some tricks/workarounds described in this article: https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-secure-origin-https/